# select the next non-identical date in data frame

Tags: r, date

I would like to generate the end date of a drug where the end date is defined as the first date where the drug is not registered. 
I have the following three drugs than can be prescribed a,b,c and the dates on which they are registered

`Drug <- c("a","b","a","b","c","a","c","a","c","c")`

```
Date <- c("2018-09-20","2018-09-20" , "2018-09-21","2018-09-21","2018-09-21",
     "2018-09-22" ,"2018-09-22" ,"2018-09-23","2018-09-23",
     "2018-09-24")
Dates <- cbind(Drug,Date)


     Drug    Date         
[1,] "a"  "2018-09-20"
[2,] "b"  "2018-09-20"
[3,] "a"  "2018-09-21"
[4,] "b"  "2018-09-21"
[5,] "c"  "2018-09-21"
[6,] "a"  "2018-09-22"
[7,] "c"  "2018-09-22"
[8,] "a"  "2018-09-23"
[9,] "c"  "2018-09-23"
[10,] "c"  "2018-09-24"
```

I would like my final table to look like this:

```
end <- c("2018-09-24","2018-09-22" ,"2018-09-24","2018-09-22" ,NA,"2018-09-24",
          NA,"2018-09-24",NA,NA)

Dates <- cbind(Dates,end)


Drug      res          end         
 "a"  "2018-09-20"  "2018-09-24"
 "b"  "2018-09-20"  "2018-09-22"
 "a"  "2018-09-21"  "2018-09-24"
 "b"  "2018-09-21"  "2018-09-22"
 "c"  "2018-09-21"  NA          
 "a"  "2018-09-22"  "2018-09-24"
 "c"  "2018-09-22"  NA          
 "a"  "2018-09-23"  "2018-09-24"
 "c"  "2018-09-23"  NA          
 "c" "2018-09-24"   NA
```

Comment: Hello @Question_poster - you should tag your question with the language/framework/software that is relevant. Also, more than 1 may be relevant.

Comment: Apologies. Thanks for pointing it out. I made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd convert your data set to a data frame to make several manipulations easier.  I would make a "helper" data frame to store the unique end date for each drug, and then join those dates onto your original data set.

Along the way, I would also make a little utility function that finds the date after a given date.  (Based on the appearance of NAs in your desired solution, I assume that when you say "the first date where the drug is not registered," you mean the first date *in your list of dates*, not just the next calendar day.)

```
library(dplyr)

Dates = as.data.frame(Dates, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

next_date <- function(one_date, all_dates) {
    all_dates <- sort(unique(all_dates))
    return(all_dates[which(one_date == all_dates)[[1]] + 1])
}

end_dates <- group_by(Dates, Drug)
end_dates <- summarize(end_dates, end = next_date(max(Date), Dates$Date))

Dates = left_join(Dates, end_dates)
```